# How to get the autogenerated task name from Google Cloud Tasks when adding Firebase Task queue functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

Following the Cloud Functions documentation about [how to Enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) it is demonstrated how to create a Firebase task queue function. This works all fine.

However, if I call the `enqueue` to enqueue the function a [Promise without any information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.functions.taskqueue.md#taskqueueenqueue) whatsoever on my queued task is returned.

→ How can I get the task name or any reference from the just created task that is added to my queue?

*I need this name to store, so I can possibly cancel my task before execution.*

Answer (score 3):

As it seems to be, Firestore Cloud functions have a limited feature set in comparison to the "real" Google Cloud Functions.

To get more data on the task, do not use the [enqueue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.functions.taskqueue.md#taskqueueenqueue) function from `firebase-admin/functions`, but make use of the `@google-cloud/tasks` library:

```ts
// Imports the Google Cloud Tasks library.
import { protos, CloudTasksClient } from "@google-cloud/tasks";

// Set all the details for the function to call
const serviceAccountEmail = "PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
const project = "PROJECT_ID";
const queue = "my-queue";
const location = "europe-west1";
const url =
    "https://europe-west1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/yourFunctionToCall";

const client = new CloudTasksClient();
const formattedParent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

const payload = {
  data: {
    your: "data"
  },
};

const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: "POST",
    url: url,
    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString("base64"),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail,
    },
  },
  scheduleTime: {
    seconds: Date.now() / 1000, // Any epcoch time in seconds, or do not set for immediate execution
  },
} as protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.ITask;

const request = {
  parent: formattedParent,
  task: task,
};

const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
functions.logger.info(`Created task ${response.name}`);
```

Calling `client.createTask` will return data on the Task. This allows you to also remove the Task if necessary.