# "Error: Queue does not exist" when queue-ing task in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have got one functions that triggers on db update:

```
exports.eventAddedTrigger = functions
  .region('europe-west6')
  .firestore
  .document('users/{user_id}/events/{event_id}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const event = snap.data();

    if (event) {
      const { user_id, event_id } = context.params;
      const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue('enrol');
      const signupDate = DateTime.fromSeconds(event.signupDate.seconds).minus({minutes: 2});
      const now = DateTime.local({zone: 'Europe/Zurich'})
      let scheduleDelaySeconds = Math.floor(signupDate.diff(now, 'seconds').seconds);
      if (scheduleDelaySeconds < 0) {
        scheduleDelaySeconds = 10;
      }
      functions.logger.info(`Scheduling enrollment for ${signupDate.toISO()} in ${scheduleDelaySeconds} seconds`);
      await queue.enqueue(
        { user_id, event_id },
        {
          scheduleDelaySeconds
        }
      )
    }
  });
```

This function triggers fine, but when it comes to enqueue-ing, I always get the following error

```
Error: Queue does not exist
```

regardless of whether I run the function emulated or in production.

The enrol function looks like this:

```
exports.enrol = functions
  .region('europe-west6')
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB',
  })
  .tasks
  .taskQueue()
  .onDispatch(async (data) => {
    const { user_id, event_id } = data.body;
    await _enrol(user_id, event_id, db);
    functions.logger.info(`Enrolled user ${user_id} to event ${event_id}`);
  });
```

I have initialised my app correctly to my best knowledge:

```
initializeApp({
  serviceAccountId: process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID,
});
```

Do I have to register the queue somewhere else?

Comment: Can you also include imports and _enrol function by editing the question ?

Comment: I am facing the very same problem. Since I cannot find this problem somewhere else this might be a very recent recession. I would love some progress or ideas on this.
For me I can tell from the logs that the dispatch listener is being initiated right after the deployment with the very name I am queueing to.

Comment: @sverrirarnors I know you found a different solution but could you check if the answer provided by me would have helped you?

Comment: @bastianowicz, the solution below looks promising! I'll comment and mark it as soon as I've got the chance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out for me. If you're using non [default region](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/functions/functions-api-client-internal.ts#L37) for your function (i.e. not us-central1) than you need to specify your queue name including your target region.
The schema is defined here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/utils/index.ts#L293

So use your enqueue function like this:

```js
await this.functions 
    .taskQueue<INotification<any>[]>(`locations/${region}/functions/${queueName}`) 
    .enqueue(data);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much - this is a quite poorly documented feature by Firebase so this insight is very valuable.

Comment: Does this also work for just `{functionName}` instead of `locations/${region}/functions/${queueName}` for non default regions. Because in the doc you have provided there is shown this option in `or` sections. And it will be also nice if you provide the reference for this method showing we can pass functionsName to `taskQueue()` method

Comment: I don't think it works with just `functionName` for non default locations. This was the whole point of this issue. But it seems I don't get your question right. Maybe you can phrase it differently again.

Comment: We are using the default location ``us-central1`` and got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this does not directly concern the OP, but I'll add this answer for others who made the same mistake as me. You can also encounter this error if your Cloud Functions are split into groups, but do not use the full name of the queue. For example, if you have a queue named "exampleQueue" in a group named "myGroup", you should use `getFunctions().taskQueue("myGroup-exampleQueue");` instead of just `getFunctions().taskQueue("exampleQueue");`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this issue and find out you need to initializeApp with the following syntax:

```
import {applicationDefault, initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";
initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
});
```

Where DATABASE_NAME will be databaseURL from your `firebaseConfig` in the console.You can get the database by visiting project settings under your apps section.

Plus you also have to enqueue the functions into queue as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions#enqueue_the_function), and make sure you enqueue your task in around 1 minute gap also you haven't included `dispatchDeadlineSeconds` in queue.enqueue like the one which is provided in above documentaions.

I have found the recommended [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) which shows initialization of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this was not the problem. I ended up solving the problem by using the more powerful Google Cloud tasks, outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309846/how-to-get-the-autogenerated-task-name-from-google-cloud-tasks-when-adding-fireb

Comment: I am pretty certain that this is not an issue with the initiattion. For me both my functions (queue listener and request listener) are being instatiated. But for whatever reason the `enqueue` function does not seem to find the queue with the name (trippled checked that)